# MySQL Installation Wizard for Microsoft Windows

Tags: mysql-workbench

I tried to install MySQL on my machine (win 8 64 bit), I downloaded mysql-5.6.24-winx64.exe and after completing MySQL 5.6 setup wizard, the MySQL Server Instance Configuration Wizard does not start and nothing happens. In the windows start menu for MySQL I have only 2 options:MySQL 5.6 command line client and MySQL 5.6 command line - Unicode.

So what can I do to resolve this problem and run MYSQL on my machine, I am waiting for your advice. Please help me I need to resolve this problem

Comment: Please avoid asking the same question again and again. Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31992546/mysql-server-instance-configuration-wizard-does-not-start For proper installation procedure: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-install-wizard.html

Comment: I need your help, i have to

Comment: Please read the documentation before diving in, I'm not sure where exactly you messed up but my wild guess is in **choosing the install type**. There are three installation types available: _Typical, Complete,_ and _Custom_. Please read the documentation and try for yourself. If you chose the _Custom_ type: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-install-wizard.html#mysql-install-wizard-custom-install

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari I tried, my problem is the MySQL Server Instance Configuration Wizard does not start automatically after completing MySQL 5.6 setup wizard

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to use the all-in-one [Windows installer](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/) for installing a MySQL server plus any additional tool you want, like MySQL Workbench, connectors or documentation. It will not only install the right package but will also do semi-automatic updates, check for prerequisites, start the configuration wizard etc.